# Access strings.xml during runtime to parse

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

I want to access `strings.xml` and `arrays.xml` at runtime ,to parse it and read my custom provided attributes.

Is this possible? If yes, how can i access it?
The thing is that I have a questionnaire and I wanted to give each question, that is defined in `strings.xml` a unique key, so that each question can be identified. 
This key I've added as a attribute.

```
<string key="keyForQuestion" name="question1">This is a question?</string>
```

Maybe there is also a way to access the name attribute? Without parsing it on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can acsess any `xml` resource by calling:

`getResources().` if you're in a `Activity` or `getActivity().getResources().` if you want to get a resource from a `Fragment`

**Exmaple from a Activity:**

```
  //gives us String
 String name =  getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

 //gives us array of String
 String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.names);

 //get a specific string from its index
 String myName = names[i]

 //get a specific key from the name
   for(int i =0; i<names.lenght(); i++{
     if(names[i].equels("hello"){
         // Key is > i
       }
    }
```

Comment: Yes I know. But with that I only get the string. I want the value of the attribute key.

Comment: @FelixWeilbach this is not something in Android, so you can't do that. What you can and should do is store all your strings in a string-array and use their index as a key.

Comment: Yes I've had that idea. But imagine I delete a question or insert one.. I had then to update everything.. A lot of work..

Comment: @FelixWeilbach i just upadted my answer with 2 extra suggestions for you